# form not being submitted on button click php

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to get my form to submit for two days but no luck. I've gone through my code backwards and forwards. The isset if the statement is not triggering. Its an amateur issue but please help me. I am using js to make the table because it is dependant on DB entries, but for simplicity sake, I have pasted the output HTML. Since I'm using js, I thought it would be easier to give them form tags instead of surrounding each row with a form. I also have the Submit in the same file. I did try to put the different file and like it via action but no cigar. I am using  Joomla platform, but I don't think that matters.

Thankyou to anyone who can help me

```html
<tr>
  <td>TA Hours <br>Unit: Hours</td>
  <td><input class="TA Hours input-mini" name="TA HoursMonday" type="number" size="6" min="0" step=".01" form="formTA Hours"></td>
  <td><input class="TA Hours input-mini" name="TA HoursTuesday" type="number" size="6" min="0" step=".01" form="formTA Hours"></td>
  <td><input class="TA Hours input-mini" name="TA HoursWednesday" type="number" size="6" min="0" step=".01" form="formTA Hours"></td>
  <td><input class="TA Hours input-mini" name="TA HoursThursday" type="number" size="6" min="0" step=".01" form="formTA Hours"></td>
  <td><input class="TA Hours input-mini" name="TA HoursFriday" type="number" size="6" min="0" step=".01" form="formTA Hours"></td>
  <td><input class="TA Hours input-mini" name="TA HoursSaturday" type="number" size="6" min="0" step=".01" form="formTA Hours"></td>
  <td><input class="TA Hours input-mini" name="TA HoursSunday" type="number" size="6" min="0" step=".01" form="formTA Hours"></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Save" name="buttonTA Hours" form="formTA Hours"></td>
  <td>

  </td>
</tr>

<form name="formTA Hours" method="post"><input type="text" name="Name" value="TA Hours" form="formTA Hours" style="display: none;"></form>
```

Heres the PHP trying to make a popup

```
</script>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['buttonTA Hours'])){
    echo 'alert("isset works")';
}
?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<tr></tr>` has to be inside the `<form>`. All the values inside the form get submitted in `$_POST` your input with name "buttonTA Hours" is not inside the form so its not being submitted.

Currently, when you submit the form all you're submitting is `<input type="text" name="Name" value="TA Hours" form="formTA Hours" style="display: none;">`

Your code should look like this:

```
<form>
  <tr>
     <td>
     ...
     ...
  </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: wouldnt the form attribute take care of that

Comment: No. only inputs inside the `<form>` get submitted.
Do `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` so you can see the values being submitted right before the if statement

Comment: I see what you mean, ive never used the form attribute on an input. 
try changing `<form name=formTA Hours` to `<form id=formTA Hours`

Comment: so the good news is the page refreshes but I'm still not getting the alert upon changing the name to id

Comment: @wasihassan do you see 'alert("isset works")' printed on the website?

Comment: nope. would putting it under the script tag be the issue for some weird reason. Ive tried taking it out but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try this `echo '<script>alert("isset works")</script>';`

Comment: tried it still nothing I think its a matter of the if statement not triggering as I had other commands under it and they weren't executing either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211401/discussion-between-altoids-and-wasi-hassan).

Comment: Im putting this down for anyone in the future  us array_key_exists("button_TA Hours",$_POST) instead of isset as the post is sending out an array from the form